# How can I connect application logs that are generated through redirects in an aspx redirect flow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I have a ASP.NET application that uses `ASPX` pages with code behind that redirects to other `ASPX` pages. I am trying to set up application logs for this application that are able to be linked between the flows.

For example, a user would start with `a.aspx`, get redirected to `b.aspx` and then to `c.aspx`. I want to log the request done to `a.aspx`, `b.aspx` and `c.aspx` and any unhandled exceptions. I also want to have a way to identify that the logs generated are part of one flow, i.e all log ids for a specific flow are the same. The order of `a.aspx`, `b.aspx` and `c.aspx` are not set, for example, I might want to log the flow that takes me through `b.aspx`, `c.aspx` and `a.aspx`.

I've tried looking at cookies to store the log id while going through the process, but I am having issues since the cookies are preserved across consecutive flows. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Cookies` if you want to persist the data in your log. There is another option you might want to look into, it is called `ELMAH` https://elmah.github.io/

As far as I understand, you would want to log the workflow (including any exceptions) in your `asp.net` application.  I think `ELMAH` would seem best fit for your requirement.

Example link on how to use [`ELMAH`logging modules](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)